# How to make a busy file not busy so it can be deleted. rm: filename: Resource busy

Tags: macos, rm

I have somehow generated a file on a network mounted volume that is in the busy state, and I have no knowledge of what could be using it. I want the file gone, and am not really concerned about whatever might be trying to use the file. I will document the process by which I created the file below.

Also, I know that there was a similar question asked before [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/550294/override-resource-is-busy-when-rm-on-mac-os-x-terminal#), but none of them have worked for me, and I can't comment on them with my current reputation to ask for clarification.

```
$echo "day" > other_tmp
$cat other_tmp
day
$sed "s/day/night/" <other_tmp>other_tmp
$vi other_tmp
```

It is empty, so I try to re-populate it to try again.

```
[i]
day
[esc]
[:wq!]
```

Something goes wrong, I get the following back

```
"other_tmp" 1L, 4C written
E207: Can't delete backup file
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The q! makes me skip this though.

```
$ls
other_tmp      other_tmp~
$rm other_tmp
$rm other_tmp~
rm: other_tmp~: Resource busy
$rm -f other_tmp~
rm: other_tmp~: Resource busy
```

That's where I got to when I started looking for help.

Most of the answers I've found suggest using `lsof filename`

```
$lsof other_tmp~
$
```

Nothing.

Others suggested renaming the file and then using finder to kill it.
    $mv other_tmp~ new_name
    $ls
    new_name
It moved to a new name successfully. But finder gave me the following error when doing `Move to Trash`.

```
The operation can’t be completed because the item “new_name_2” is in use.
```

And this is where I am now. Except I ran through the process again to see if it was reproducible so now I have `new_name` and `new_name_2`.

I can't restart the volume, because I don't have those permissions. I just want to delete the files. Its not a terrible high priority given that their filesize is 0, but they are are enough of a nuisance that I have gone this far to try to remove them.

====UPDATE====

```
$fuser new_name
new_name:
$
```

Comment: Look for fuser or lsof (or the equivalent in OSX) that could tell you what process keeps the file open and kill that process if possible.

Comment: lsof returns nothing.

fuser returns `new_user:` and nothing else.

Comment: Then my only reasonable hint is out. I can give you an improbable one as well (with half an hour of experience on Mac): if the file status is cached and bound you id, a windows-like logoff/logon may help.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Someone (not here) recommended restarting the machine I was on with the off chance that even though no process could be found it was hiding somewhere. I did that and it worked. I hadn't done that earlier because I don't have a good way to get all my windows back open and in the correct places.

Comment: Yep, rebooting really had to work. It left the question open if the binding had been left in the kernel's file system handler or in some user pool cache but in the court of Mac we don't have to know everything anyway. Maybe next time... ;)

Comment: i have done the same commands as you on my mac to try to reproduce your problem - for me it worked all fine as expected - can you tell us something more about the kind of network share you're using - is it a single drive or a raid drive or maybe a zpool or a drive which is under some sort of a backup tool e.g. time maschine drive - also can you reproduce this error with another network share or with another editor (nano, emacs)?

Comment: Running it on my machine off the mount, the rm worked fine. As far as using a particular editor, I have found that if I don't try to edit it, then the original file with exhibit the same qualities of being busy. So it does this before trying to edit and editing just transfers the issue to the *~ file. I don't think I have another drive to mount. The original drive is my home directory at work. I probably can't go into details, but I would assume any company would use Raid and backup such directories. I'd guess NFS for the type of storage.

Comment: Okay, figured it out. I was running a unix file system through a cifs mount to another unix file system and something was going wrong in there. It worked when I switch to using NFS. I didn't realize I had an option on that one.